# how I can properly restrict access to the backend(API) server only from the frontend layer while deploying multi-tire app using security groups?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I'm implementing a three-tier architecture on **AWS** for my web application. The architecture consists of a presentation layer (React), an application layer (Node.js), and a database layer (MySQL). To deploy it, I have created two EC2 instances for the frontend and backend, respectively, and one RDS instance for the database.

The frontend layer handles user requests and communicates with the backend layer to retrieve data from the database. To ensure secure communication, I have set up three security groups: one for the frontend, one for the backend, and one for the database.

The frontend security group allows access from anywhere on the internet, as it needs to be accessible by users. However, I want to restrict access to the backend layer only from the frontend layer, for enhanced security. For this purpose, I have configured the backend security group to allow requests on port 80 (HTTP) only from the frontend security group. NOTE: All the SG's outbound rules are configured as **All traffic anywhere**. it won't create any issues.
[see this image to get more idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bInsJ.png)

However, this configuration in the security group is not working as expected. The communication between the frontend and backend is not established. and I'm getting errors like TIME_OUT as shown in the image here [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsBMb.png)

I used Reachability Analyzer to see what's and where it's going wrong. but it shows that your backend accepting traffic from frontend on port 80 and the test is successful.
[Analyzer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u26O2.png)

but my application is unable to call the API. even it's not reaching to the backend otherwise I can see the API request logs.

**Surprisingly, when I allow all traffic on port 80 from any IP address (ALL_IP) instead of just the frontend security group, the communication starts working.**
[all traffic from internet on port 80](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n82v5.png)

And it starts fetching the data from the database and renders on the frontend. [working demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsYWT.png)

but I can't allow ALL IP addresses to access my backend. and if I allow just frontend SG to access the backend then my application stops working. I don't know why it's happening. it is strange behavior because it should not happen.

I have spent a considerable amount of time (more than a week) trying to resolve this issue, but I haven't made any progress.

Can you please help me understand why my current configuration is not working and how I can properly restrict access to the backend layer only from the frontend layer using security groups?

I'm sharing the GitHub link: https://github.com/AnkitJodhani/2nd10WeeksofCloudOps.git

Comment: I'm not sure, since you've not actually said _which_ component is timing out trying to make the request, but it sounds like you want the user agent (in other words, the Web Browser) to make the request in question.  That will require access from the IP of the user's machine, not the IP of the your front end or back end.

Comment: Your understanding of this type of architecture is pretty flawed. Your front end is served from resources residing in a specific security group. However, client requests wouldn’t be originating from this security group, since they would be initiated by the user agent accessing the frontend.

Comment: “*I want to restrict access to the backend layer only from the frontend layer, for enhanced security.*” What *specifically* do you believe enhances security here?

Comment: so that no one can access the API except the frontend of the application.